# Mailjet API: how to add template parameters?

Tags: php, email, mailjet

I use the Mailjet API [PHP library](https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php-simple). And I want to send an email with a *template*.

How can I add *template parameters* to my function `sendEmail`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Template parameters can not be added in the function "sendEmail". However, you can add template parameters using the function "send". Please note that it requires JSON payload. See here:
https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php-simple/blob/master/doc/_send-api.md#sending-a-basic-email

Also, please note that the wrapper you use [mailjet-apiv3-php-simple](https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php-simple) is considered deprecated and is on maintenance only. We strongly advise you to consider implementing our [new PHP wrapper](https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php).

P.S.
Question linked to Github issue - https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php-simple/issues/130